# TypeError: client.on is not a function -error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I keep getting this error, TypeError: client.on is not a function

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this issue?

Here's the code:

```
  const DiscordPage = d;
  await fill_discord(DiscordPage, username, password, email);

  const client = d._client;
  var token;

  client.on('Network.webSocketFrameSent', ({requestId, timestamp, response}) => {
    try {
      const json = JSON.parse(response.payloadData);
      if(!token && json["d"]["token"]){
        token = json["d"]["token"];
        write_log(true, `Token: ${token}`);
      };
    } catch(e){};
  })
  await break_captcha(DiscordPage);
```

Comment: So what is `d`?

Comment: const client = d && d._client &&  d._client;

Comment: i forgot to add the first line